# Cannot use Dialog box in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create a dialog box in android with an edit text in it, this edit text returns some text to a fragment inside main activity

```
class NameDialog : AppCompatDialogFragment() {

    private  lateinit var listener: NameDialogListener

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        try{
            listener = context as NameDialogListener
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Timber.d("Must implement NameDialog Listener")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder : AlertDialog.Builder  = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        val layoutInflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater
        val view =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.name_dialog_box , null)

        val editText = view.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.Dialog_textField)

        builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Change Handle")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ -> }
            .setPositiveButton("Confirm") { _, _ ->
                val handle = editText.text.toString()
                listener.applyUsername(handle)
            }

        return builder.create()

    }

    interface NameDialogListener{
        fun applyUsername(handle :String)
    }
}
```

But when I click positive button on the dialog box my app crashes with this error message

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property listener has not been initialized
        at com.carrot.trucoder2.utils.NameDialog.access$getListener$p(NameDialog.kt:13)
        at com.carrot.trucoder2.utils.NameDialog$onCreateDialog$2.onClick(NameDialog.kt:40)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:177)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
```

Here is my fragment

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_settings) , NameDialog.NameDialogListener {

    val viewModel: DetailsViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        button.setOnClickListener{
              openDialog()
        }
    }
    private fun openDialog(){
            val dialog = NameDialog()
            dialog.show(childFragmentManager , "Name change Dialog")
        }

        override fun applyUsername(handle: String) {
         //toast handle
         }
}
```

Can someone help me fix this problem?
Thank you :-)

Comment: Make sure your activity implements NameDialog Listener

Comment: `listener = context as NameDialogListener` – If the `Fragment` is your listener, then you need to use `parentFragment` there instead of `context`. Also, make sure you're using `childFragmentManager` in the `show()` call, not just `fragmentManager`.

Comment: Yeah, you're mostly there already. Just change `context` to `parentFragment` in that cast.

Comment: It worked. Thank you